# Writing reports with Perl

Tags: perl, format

I am trying to write out multiple report files using perl. Each file has the same structure, but with different data. So, my basic code looks something like

```
#begin code
our $log_fh;
open %log_fh, ">" . $logfile

our $rep;

if (multipleReports)
{
   while (@reports) {
     printReport($report[0]);
   }
}

sub printReports
{
   open $rep, ">" . $[0];
   printHeaders();
   printBody();
   close $rep;
}

sub printHeader() {
format HDR =
@>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
$generatedLine
.

format HDR_TOP =
.

$rep->format_name("HDR");
$rep->format_top_name("HDR_TOP");

$generatedLine = "test";
write($rep);
$generatedLine = "next item";
write($rep);
$generatedLine = "last header item";
write($rep);
}

sub printBody #There are multiple such sections in my code. For simplicity, I have just shown 1 here
{
 #declare own header and header top. Set report to use these and print items to $rep
}

#end code
```

The above is just a high level of the code I am using and I hope I have captured all the salient points. However, for some reason, I get the first report file output correctly. The second file instead of having in the first section

test
               next item
               last item

reads

last item
               last item
               last item

I have tried a whole lot of options primarily around autoflush, but, for the life of me can't figure out why it is doing this. I am using Perl 5.8.2. Any help/pointers much appreciated.

Thanks
George

Edit 1
I tried passing the filehandle as a parameter to the subroutines, but, was still seeing the issue. 
I then move the format statement outside the subroutine and declared the $generated variable as a global. This seemed to fix it. I think for some reason declaring the format each time, the subroutine was being called, seemed to be messing it up. Not sure exactly why.
Wierd thing though is, I moved the format statement back to inside the subroutine (I didn't like the idea of declaring all the variables in all my format statements to be global). But,this time I changed the declaration to be

```
my $generatedLine = "";
my $format = "format HDR = \n" .
'@>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>' . "\n" .
'$generatedLine' . "\n" .
'.';

my $formatTop = "format HDR_TOP = \n".
'.';

   eval $format;
   eval $formatTop;
```

This seems to work as well - I see the correct output in my multiple files (well..I am currently only testing with 2 files..I will be doing some more testing tomorrow).

Any idea why declaring the format this way seems to work? Is there something special going on with eval?

Thanks
George

Comment: @user346526: Welcome to StackOverflow! I've formatted the code block for you -- to achieve the same result on future questions and answers, after posting code, select it and click the "Code" button in the toolbar.

Comment: @josh: thanks..for a moment there I was wondering how it almost magically got formatted :)

Comment: @ georgemp : Are you using `strict` and `warnings`? They more often than not will help get rid of silly little things. Also, please take the time to ensure that your code is as complete as the question requires and error-free as well. I can already spot a few typos that I'm sure you didn't mean to be there; it helps others get down to the nitty-gritty of your issue when these little things are taken care of.

Comment: Some probable typos: `while (@reports) { printReport($report[0]); }` will print the first report over and over again.  `$_[0]` is the first argument to a routine, not `$[0]`.

Comment: Perl formats are kinda weird and clunky.  Unless you're doing complicated reports, consider using `printf`.

Comment: @schwern - $report[0] was a typo. I didn't put in the whole code as it is a pretty complicated report over 1000 lines and I was trying to break it down to a manageable chunk for me to pose a question. I would rather not have to use printf as there are so many sections of the report, each having different headers and running into multiple pages. I would then have to manually keep track of number of lines used on a single page etc.

Comment: @georgemp Also see http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Text::Report.

Comment: @zaid - Moved previous post to answer section back to question.

Answer (score 8):

I've never used it, but [Text::Report](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Text::Report) looks promising if you are making complex reports.

Regarding more general matters, your code makes me think you are not running with `use strict` and `use warnings`. If not, turn them on. That will provide many clues.

Also, you appear to be using subroutines, which is good, but not taking advantage of one of their primary purposes -- namely, to provide well-defined areas for variable scoping. For example, why does `$rep` need to be a global variable? If a subroutine needs some information, pass it in as an argument. Especially when your program attempts to perform the same task over and over -- such as generating a bunch of reports -- you need to be careful not to allow variables from one iteration retain stale values during subsequent iterations.

Exercising some basic discipline in the organization of your program will largely solve such problems. Here is a simple illustration.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

# Example usage: perl script.pl foo.txt bar.txt
main(@ARGV);

sub main {
    my @report_names = @_;
    for my $rep_name (@report_names) {
        my @fake_data = map rand(), 1..10;
        printReport($rep_name, @fake_data);
    }
}

sub printReport {
    my ($rep_name, @data) = @_;
    open my $fh, ">", $rep_name or die $!;
    printHeader($fh);
    printBody($fh, @data);
    close $fh;
}

sub printHeader() {
    my $fh = shift;
    print $fh "Header\n";
}

sub printBody {
    my ($fh, @data) = @_;
    print $fh "Body\n";
    print $fh $_, "\n" for @data;
}
```

Comment: FWIW I'd pass the data around as a reference to avoid copying it every call, but references might be overwhelming at this stage.

Comment: @FM - I will try this out...passing the filehandle as an argument. I do have use strict; and use warnings; in my program. It doesn't throw out any errors/warnings.
@FM/Schwern - Thanks for the responses

Answer (score 0):

I think what is happening is that in my original code, the format statement is behaving something like a static. It is being executed only once when the subroutine is called first. The next time the subroutine is called, since, the format is not being evaluated, the format variable $generatedLine points to the previous stale variable from the last call of the subroutine. Calling write() is hence just re-writing that same text from the last subroutine call.
With the new method, it is evaluating format every time the subroutine is called, and hence, the format variable $generatedLine points to the latest local $generatedLine associated with the new subroutine call. So, it prints out the correct data.